# Ingreso de datos arroja datatype mismatch (code 20)

Tags: android, android-studio, android-sqlite, sqldatatypes

El problema sucede al iniciar la app con SQlite se cae por el tema que dice que datos datos que no coinciden si alguien tiene alguna idea sobre este error seria de gran ayuda cualquier aporte para solucionarlo

**Helper**

```
public class ConexionHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "DAATAA";
private static final int VERSION = 2;


public static final String TABLE = "pizza";
public static final String ID = "id";
public static final String NOMBRE = "nombre";
public static final String FOTO = "foto1";
public static final String INGREDIENTE1 = "igrediente1";
public static final String INGREDIENTE2 = "igrediente2";
public static final String INGREDIENTE3 = "igrediente3";
public static final String INGREDIENTE4 = "igrediente4";
public static final String CALIFICACION = "calificacion";
public static final String DESCRIPCION = "descripcion";
public static final String PRECIO = "precio";

public ConexionHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, VERSION);
}


@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    String script = "";
    script += "create table " + TABLE + "(";
    script += ID + " integer primary key autoincrement,";
    script += NOMBRE + " text,";
    script += FOTO + " text,";
    script += INGREDIENTE1 + " text,";
    script += INGREDIENTE2 + " text,";
    script += INGREDIENTE3 + " text,";
    script += INGREDIENTE4 + " text,";
    script += CALIFICACION + " integer";
    script += DESCRIPCION + " text,";
    script += PRECIO + " integer";
    script += ");";
    db.execSQL(script);
    db.execSQL("insert into " + TABLE + " values( 'Española',"+ R.drawable.pizza_espanola+" , "+R.drawable.espa_ola1+" , "+R.drawable.espa_ola2+"  , "+R.drawable.espa_ola3+"  , "+R.drawable.espa_ola4+"  ,5, 'ÑAMI ÑAMI',7500);");
    db.execSQL("insert into " + TABLE + " values( 'Todas Las Carnes'," + R.drawable.todascarne + "," + R.drawable.todas1 + "," + R.drawable.todas2 + " ," + R.drawable.todas3 + " ," + R.drawable.todas4 + " ,4, 'DELICHIUSS',5500);");
    db.execSQL("insert into " + TABLE + " values( 'Vegetariana'," + R.drawable.vegetariana + "," + R.drawable.veg1 + "," + R.drawable.veg2 + " ," + R.drawable.veg3 + " ," + R.drawable.veg4 + " ,3, 'KAKAKAK',1500);");



}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    db.execSQL("drop table " + TABLE);
    onCreate(db);
}
```

}

**CRUD**

```
public class CRUD {
private ConexionHelper helper;
private ContentValues values;
private SQLiteDatabase db;


public CRUD(Context context) {
    helper = new ConexionHelper(context);
    values = new ContentValues();
}

public void insert(Pizza p) {
    db = helper.getWritableDatabase();
    values.clear();
    values.put(ConexionHelper.NOMBRE, p.nombre);
    values.put(ConexionHelper.FOTO, p.foto1);
    values.put(ConexionHelper.INGREDIENTE1, p.igrediente1);
    values.put(ConexionHelper.INGREDIENTE2, p.igrediente2);
    values.put(ConexionHelper.INGREDIENTE3, p.igrediente3);
    values.put(ConexionHelper.INGREDIENTE4, p.igrediente4);
    values.put(ConexionHelper.CALIFICACION, p.calificacion);
    values.put(ConexionHelper.DESCRIPCION, p.descripcion);
    values.put(ConexionHelper.PRECIO, p.precio);

    db.insert(ConexionHelper.TABLE, null, values);
    db.close();
}

public void delete(String id) {
    String pk = id + "";
    db = helper.getWritableDatabase();
    db.delete(ConexionHelper.TABLE,
            ConexionHelper.ID + "=?",
            new String[]{pk});
    db.close();
}

public void update(Pizza p) {
    db = helper.getWritableDatabase();
    values.clear();
    values.put(ConexionHelper.NOMBRE, p.nombre);
    values.put(ConexionHelper.FOTO, p.foto1);
    values.put(ConexionHelper.INGREDIENTE1, p.igrediente1);
    values.put(ConexionHelper.INGREDIENTE2, p.igrediente2);
    values.put(ConexionHelper.INGREDIENTE3, p.igrediente3);
    values.put(ConexionHelper.INGREDIENTE4, p.igrediente4);
    values.put(ConexionHelper.CALIFICACION, p.calificacion);
    values.put(ConexionHelper.DESCRIPCION, p.descripcion);
    values.put(ConexionHelper.PRECIO, p.precio);

    String pk = p.id + "";//String.valueOf(m.id);
    db.update(ConexionHelper.TABLE,
            values,
            ConexionHelper.ID + "=?",
            new String[]{pk});

    db.close();
}

public Pizza find(String id) {
    Pizza p = new Pizza();
    db = helper.getReadableDatabase();
    String sql = "select * from " + ConexionHelper.TABLE + " where " + ConexionHelper.ID + "=?";
    String pk = id + "";
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(sql, new String[]{pk});

    if (cursor.moveToNext()) {
        p.id = cursor.getString(0);
        p.nombre = cursor.getString(1);
        p.foto1 = cursor.getInt(2);
        p.igrediente1 = cursor.getInt(3);
        p.igrediente2 = cursor.getInt(4);
        p.igrediente3 = cursor.getInt(5);
        p.igrediente4 = cursor.getInt(6);
        p.calificacion = cursor.getInt(7);
        p.descripcion = cursor.getString(8);
        p.precio = cursor.getInt(9);
    }
    db.close();
    return p;
}

public List<Pizza> pizzaList() {
    List<Pizza> list = new ArrayList<>();
    db = helper.getReadableDatabase();
    String sql = "select * from " + ConexionHelper.TABLE;
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(sql, null);

    while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
        Pizza p = new Pizza();
        p.id = cursor.getString(0);
        p.nombre = cursor.getString(1);
        p.foto1 = cursor.getInt(2);
        p.igrediente1 = cursor.getInt(3);
        p.igrediente2 = cursor.getInt(4);
        p.igrediente3 = cursor.getInt(5);
        p.igrediente4 = cursor.getInt(6);
        p.calificacion = cursor.getInt(7);
        p.descripcion = cursor.getString(8);
        p.precio = cursor.getInt(9);

        list.add(p);
    }
    db.close();

    return list;

}
```

}

**Logcat**

```
    2018-11-12 00:14:19.311 11014-11014/? E/SQLiteLog: (20) statement aborts at 5: [insert into pizza values( 'Española',2131165324 , 2131165287 , 2131165288  , 2131165289  , 2131165290  ,5, 'ÑAMI ÑAMI',7500);] datatype mismatch
```

2018-11-12 00:14:19.312 11014-11014/? D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
2018-11-12 00:14:19.313 11014-11014/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.proyecto.pizzaappproyect, PID: 11014
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.proyecto.pizzaappproyect/com.example.proyecto.pizzaappproyect.MainActivity}: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatatypeMismatchException: datatype mismatch (code 20)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2668)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2729)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1480)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6169)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:891)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:781)
     Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatatypeMismatchException: datatype mismatch (code 20)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativeExecuteForChangedRowCount(Native Method)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.executeForChangedRowCount(SQLiteConnection.java:734)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.executeForChangedRowCount(SQLiteSession.java:754)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.executeUpdateDelete(SQLiteStatement.java:64)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.executeSql(SQLiteDatabase.java:1679)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.execSQL(SQLiteDatabase.java:1608)
        at com.example.proyecto.pizzaappproyect.DB.ConexionHelper.onCreate(ConexionHelper.java:47)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:251)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getReadableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:187)
        at com.example.proyecto.pizzaappproyect.DB.CRUD.pizzaList(CRUD.java:97)
        at com.example.proyecto.pizzaappproyect.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:59)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6692)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2621)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2729) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1480) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6169) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:891) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:781)

**FOTO**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola Renan, veo que has realizado otras preguntas anteriormente,no olvides realizar el [tour] del sitio para conocer el funcionamiento del mismo, saludos!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

De acuerdo a el error mostrado en el `LogCat`:

> SQLiteLog: (20) statement aborts at 5: [insert into pizza values(
>   'Española',2131165324 , 2131165287 , 2131165288  , 2131165289  ,
>   2131165290  ,5, 'ÑAMI ÑAMI',7500);] datatype mismatch

El problema es que alguno o varios valores que tratas de insertar en la tabla son del tipo incorrecto, esta es la estructura de tu tabla y los tipos de los campos:

```
 script += "create table " + TABLE + "(";
    script += ID + " integer primary key autoincrement,";
    script += NOMBRE + " text,";
    script += FOTO + " text,";
    script += INGREDIENTE1 + " text,";
    script += INGREDIENTE2 + " text,";
    script += INGREDIENTE3 + " text,";
    script += INGREDIENTE4 + " text,";
    script += CALIFICACION + " integer";
    script += DESCRIPCION + " text,";
    script += PRECIO + " integer";
    script += ");";
```

**Estas tratando de insertar valores tipo `INTEGER` en donde tienes definidos campos `TEXT` lo cual es incorrecto**:

```
 db.execSQL("insert into " + TABLE + " values( 'Española',"+ R.drawable.pizza_espanola+" , "+R.drawable.espa_ola1+" , "+R.drawable.espa_ola2+"  , "+R.drawable.espa_ola3+"  , "+R.drawable.espa_ola4+"  ,5, 'ÑAMI ÑAMI',7500);");
```

Puedes realizar este cambio:

```
 db.execSQL("insert into " + TABLE + " values( 'Española', '"+ R.drawable.pizza_espanola+"' , '"+R.drawable.espa_ola1+"' , '"+R.drawable.espa_ola2+"'  , '"+R.drawable.espa_ola3+"'  , '"+R.drawable.espa_ola4+"'  ,5, 'ÑAMI ÑAMI',7500);");
```

---

En tu método `find()` estas obteniendo valores tipo `INTEGER` de campos que previamente definiste como `TEXT`, lo cual también es incorrecto:

```
public Pizza find(String id) {
    Pizza p = new Pizza();
    db = helper.getReadableDatabase();
    String sql = "select * from " + ConexionHelper.TABLE + " where " + ConexionHelper.ID + "=?";
    String pk = id + "";
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(sql, new String[]{pk});

    if (cursor.moveToNext()) {
        p.id = cursor.getString(0);
        p.nombre = cursor.getString(1);
        p.foto1 = cursor.getInt(2);
        p.igrediente1 = cursor.getInt(3);
        p.igrediente2 = cursor.getInt(4);
        p.igrediente3 = cursor.getInt(5);
        p.igrediente4 = cursor.getInt(6);
        p.calificacion = cursor.getInt(7);
        p.descripcion = cursor.getString(8);
        p.precio = cursor.getInt(9);
    }
    db.close();
    return p;
}
```

---

Es importante saber que si deseas guardar los id´s de imágenes que se encuentran en tu proyecto como son:

```
R.drawable.pizza_espanola
R.drawable.espa_ola1
R.drawable.espa_ola2
R.drawable.espa_ola3
R.drawable.espa_ola4
```

lo recomendable sería guardarlos en campos tipo `INTEGER`.

Answer (score 0):

Si vas a guardar imagenes de recursos drawables la columna debe ser int.

```
 script += FOTO + " integer,";
```

Para insertar una imagen creas un int de ese drawable:

```
 int pizza_es = R.drawable.pizza_espanola;

  // y así se inserta sin comillas, el ID de ese int
  db.execSQL("insert into " + TABLE + " values( 'Española',pizza_es ,...
```

Lo lees así como lo tienes, como int:

```
p.foto1 = cursor.getInt(2);
```

Comment: No sabia el tema de int en las fotos te lo agradezco mucho pero al momento de hacer el int de las fotos al drawable no me toman las variables y me arroja un error que no encuentra las columnas te adjunto una foto al final del post del error

Comment: elimina la app del emulador/dispositivo y luego la reinstalas